# Plotly: How to hide the lines overlapped with bubbles?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I have been updating my program Bubble Diagram (Version3.1) which is operated with the GUI. It reads data from an xlsx file and plot the Bubble Diagram within four simple steps. This latest version has mainly beautified and standardized the style of the diagram so that it looks more harmonious with different scenarios.
[image: GUI]
[image: overlapped line]
example data(.xlsx):

```
             1991  1992  1993  1994  1995  1996  1997  1998  1999  2000
         US    10    14    16    18    20    42    64   100    50    88
      JAPAN   100    30    70    85    30    42    64    98    24    60
         CN    50    22    30    65    70    66    60    45    45    50
      INDIA    90    88    35    50    90    60    40    66    76    70
         UK    40    50    70    50    25    30    22    40    60    55
   MALAYSIA    30    50    44    25    30    15    19    22    50    66
```

Part of the vertical and horizontal gridlines which overlapped with each bubble should be invisible. How can I make it?

```
# Bubble Diagram Version3.1

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.path1 = fd.StringVar()
        self.path2 = fd.StringVar()
        self.name_input = fd.StringVar()
        group_1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=15, pady=10,
                                text="Input and Output Settings")
        group_1.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        tk.Label(group_1, text='Step1').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(group_1, text="Import data from",
                  highlightbackground='green',
                  width=20, command=self.choose_file).grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Label(group_1, textvariable=self.path1, width=40, bg='grey', fg='white').grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5)
        tk.Label(group_1, text='Step2').grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(group_1, text="Set output path", highlightbackground='orange',
                  width=20, command=self.choose_directory).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Label(group_1, textvariable=self.path2, width=40, bg='grey', fg='white').grid(row=1, column=2, pady=5)
        tk.Label(group_1, text='Step3').grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Label(group_1, text='Input name WITHOUT suffix', bg='SteelBlue', width=20).grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Entry(group_1, textvariable=self.name_input, bg='grey', width=40).grid(row=2, column=2)

        group_2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=15, pady=10, text="Implementation")
        group_2.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        tk.Label(group_2, text='Step4').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(group_2, text="Start to plot", highlightbackground='red',
                  width=10, command=self.start).grid(row=0, column=1)

    def choose_file(self):
        filetypes = (("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),
                     )
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open file",
                                           initialdir="/", filetypes=filetypes)
        self.path1.set(self.filename)

    def choose_directory(self):
        self.directory = fd.askdirectory(title="Open directory",
                                         initialdir="/")
        self.path2.set(self.directory)

    def start(self):
        self.draw(self.filename, self.directory)

    def draw(self, input_file, output_dir):
        self.input_file = input_file
        self.output_dir = output_dir
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.input_file)
        sheet = wb['Sheet1']
        row_max = sheet.max_row
        col_max = sheet.max_column
        first_row_list = []
        first_col_list = []
        for col_n in range(2, col_max + 1):
            first_row_list.append(sheet.cell(row=1, column=col_n).value)
        for row_n in range(2, row_max + 1):
            first_col_list.append(sheet.cell(row=row_n, column=1).value)

        data_all = pd.read_excel(self.input_file)
        data_selected = data_all.loc[:, first_row_list]

        df = pd.DataFrame(data_selected)
        df.index = first_col_list
        colors = ['rgb(150,204,90)', 'rgb(255, 130, 71)', 'rgb(255, 193, 37)', 'rgb(180,240,190)', 'rgb(255, 10, 1)',
                  'rgb(25, 190, 30)', 'rgb(100, 100, 100)', 'rgb(45,24,200)', 'rgb(33, 58, 108)', 'rgb(35, 208, 232)']

        data = [go.Scatter(
            x=df.columns,
            y=[country] * len(df.columns),
            mode='markers+text',
            marker=dict(
                color=colors[num],
                size=df.loc[country],
                showscale=False,
            ),
            text=list(map(str, df.loc[country])),
            textposition='middle center',
        )
            for num, country in enumerate(reversed(df.index))
        ]

        layout = go.Layout(plot_bgcolor='white',
                           paper_bgcolor='white',
                           font={
                               'size': 15,
                               'family': 'sans-serif',
                               'color': 'black'
                           },
                           width=1000,
                           height=800,
                           xaxis=dict(
                               nticks=col_max + 1,
                               type='category',
                               showline=True,
                               linecolor='black',
                               mirror=True,
                               showgrid=True,
                               gridcolor='black',
                           ),
                           yaxis=dict(
                               showline=True,
                               linecolor='black',
                               mirror=True,
                               showgrid=True,
                               gridcolor='black',
                           ),
                           showlegend=False,
                           margin=dict(l=100, r=100, t=100, b=100),
                           hovermode=False,
                           )

        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        self.name = self.name_input.get() + '.html'
        py.offline.plot(fig, filename=os.path.join(self.output_dir, self.name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.title("Bubble Diagram")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Of all the tags it seems only `plotly` is related to this question.

Comment: @HenryYik I've deleted the unrelated tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a matter of opacity. The markers you are plotting are partially transparent, which means they allow the gridlines behind them to be shown. I think one way to solve this is to make the markers opaque, through `go.Scatter()`, as follows:

```
data = [go.Scatter(
        x=df.columns,
        y=[country] * len(df.columns),
        mode='markers+text',
        marker=dict(
            color=colors[num],
            size=df.loc[country],
            showscale=False,
            opacity=1,
        ),
        text=list(map(str, df.loc[country])),
        textposition='middle center',
    )
        for num, country in enumerate(reversed(df.index))
    ]
```

to maximize the visibility of density.

The Plotly documentation has a nice [article](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/) about the different options for where you could specify an opacity, and you can also see what it looks like in the examples.

Comment: OMG, I can not conceal my excitement while the problem is fixed with your great help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I was of help! :D